# iPhone design portal like "Android Design" portal

Tags: iphone

I can't seem to find any official iPhone design portal like Google developers made for Android (http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

Does such exist at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is Apple's **iOS Human Interface Guidelines**:

- [Web](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [PDF](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf)
- [eBook](http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/ios-human-interface-guidelines/id409933219?mt=11)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).